# Propagating dark mode changes across all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way of getting the changes of enabling/disabling dark mode to propagate on all pages of my site without changing the CSS?

My jQuery.js code

```
onload = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("darkMode") === "true") {
        var mode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
        enableDarkMode();
    }
}

function enableDarkMode() {
    $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
    $( "nav" ).removeClass( "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light");
    $( "nav" ).addClass( "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark");
    $( '.inner-switch' ).text( "ON" );
    var mode = localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "true");
}

function disableDarkMode() {
    $( "body" ).removeClass( "dark" );
    $( "nav" ).removeClass( "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark");
    $( "nav" ).addClass( "navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light");
    $( '.inner-switch' ).text( "OFF" );
    var mode = localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "false");
}

$( '.inner-switch' ).on("click", function() {
    if( $( "body" ).hasClass( "dark" )) {
        disableDarkMode();
    } else {
        enableDarkMode();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: You could use PHP

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a working solution in your question. You can simply put that code into a $(document).read() statement and implement it once the user loads the page.

Alternatively, you can set a timer to check on the value of your darkMode variable and update on change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please clarify? I need to propagate the changes to all pages if Dark mode is enabled.

Comment: I can't see your code base, but I'm assuming that clicking different links will take you to different pages, each with their own HTML, CSS, and javascript logic. Is that accurate?

If this is the case, you would most likely want to go to each relevant javascript logic file and literally copy-paste the code that you have written here into the javascript file. It ought to execute as soon as the page is loaded, then update the page accordingly. Have you tried this already, and is it not executing for you?